# AWS cdk environment strategy: one per branch, one per developer, or only dev/staging/prod?

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops

we're currently setup with a dev, staging, and prod environments on aws. We're finding it hard to do QA properly, since often many commits happen in a short span of time, and are all included in a codepipeline build, which makes it hard to associate failures to a specific commit.

We were looking into spinning up one environment per feature branch, in a manner similar what this [aws quickstart example](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/serverless-cicd-for-enterprise/) is doing:

[image]

However, I'm finding it hard to justify spinning up our entire backend (which is huge) to test, in some cases, a single apigateway->lambda->dynamodb route. Furthermore, this can work for serverless services, but we also use elasticsearch server. In such a case, it doesn't even seem possible to spin an ES server just for testing a new feature branch. But if we point our feature branch to, say, staging's ES server, how do we make sure not to pollute it in case of bugs?

How do people usually go about solving this problem?

Comment: Pasting the chart from the vanilla quickstart example doesn't help to understand *your* problem. Are you using the same pipeline for everything, or do you have separate pipelines for each CodeCommit branch? can't you do specific testing without the need to spin up a full-sized backend?

Comment: Right now we have 10ish pipelines (for each service) for 3 branches (so 30ish in total): dev, staging, and prod. What do you mean by specific testing?